# number of moves needed to get closest to a sorted array (increasing)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

The rules to sort the array are:
you are allowed to pick either the first or the last element of the array and use it as the first element of the new array, repeat the process and get the new array complete.
Then repeat process on the new array
Ex:

```
Old Line = 5 3 4 3 2 7
New Line = Empty

Old Line = 3 4 3 2 7
New Line = 5

Old Line = 3 4 3 2
New Line = 5 7

Old Line = 4 3 2
New Line = 3 5 7

Old Line = 3 2
New Line = 4 3 5 7

Old Line = 2
New Line = 3 4 3 5 7

Old Line = Empty
New Line = 2 3 4 3 5 7
```

Here, this is the best we can get to, but we are allowed to use the final new line as old line again to make a more sorted array if possible.

Comment: Do you want to minimize the number of inversions in the array?

Comment: @axyz no. I want to know when to stop the process.

Comment: How is the "distance" to the sorted array measured ?

Comment: @secretstuff - There is a conflict between the problem statement and the example. When 7 is removed from Old Line, it is appended to the end of New Line instead of being "used as the first element of the new array".